# How to deploy an Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

Environment: **Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), Build id: 20180405-1200**

I have completely developed my new Eclipse Plugin. I have debugged it successfully and It´s ready to be deployed for beta testing by other developers in my organization.

The **Overview** tab in `plugin.xml` Eclipse editor offers an **Export Wizard** that works and produces a `.jar` file (*theoretically*) containing the plugin to be installed in other Eclipse installations.

After exporting the plugin to a local folder in my computer I tried to install it in Eclipse by using **Help > Install new software... > [Add...] > [Archive...]**, selecting the `.jar` file generated and clicking **[Ok]**.

However, I get the error message `"Could not find jar:file:*<the selected plugin file>*!"` and the **[Finnish]** button remains disabled.

What is missing to make my new plugin fully installable?

Comment: I'm not sure about this dialog, but you can install a plugin manually by dropping its `jar` file into the `eclipse/plugins/` directory.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know, but I read some answers here in StackOverflow discouraging this practice. Besides, if there is a GUI for such a task, it must work. I'm not much into doing things behind the curtains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most robust way to publish a plug-in (or Feature) for others to consume is to produce an Update Site. Then you can direct users to that site so they can install your plug-is/features via the [Install New Software UI](http://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-124.htm). It also provides an easy way to publish updates to your plug-ins.

Here is [documentation about creating an Update Site](http://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fupdate_site.htm&cp=4_1_6).

Comment: It's not a broken link, the documentation web site is just down today. I'll email the Eclipse webmasters.